# Apache Camel Converting JSON to JMS

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

I am trying to convert information in a route that is in JSON format into JMS format so that I can send it to a topic.

Looking at [the docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/json-jackson-dataformat.html), I see:

```
from("activemq:My.Queue").
  marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson).
  to("mqseries:Another.Queue");
```

Is it correct to interpret here that we have marshalled the message from the queue into JSON, then  when sending it to the other queue, it has been converted back to a JMS message?
If not, how can we achieve this conversion using the Java DSL?
Further, is it possible to add key-value pairs to the JSON along the Camel route?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any kind of data to a JMS queue. The `marshal().json` suggests that the data in `My.Queue` was a java object, which was converted into json format. The `Another.Queue` queue is receiving a json object.

You can also transform your data anyway you want before passing the data to the consumer.

Comment: What would be the difference between sending the data without marshalling it first and sending it after marshalling? Do we convert to JSON for convenience?

Comment: I think that example was just showing you could convert to json without much of a hassle. You could just as easily remove the marshal to json, which means your camel route will be picking pojos from My.Queue and just transferring those to Another.Queue